# Install dplyr package in R for MS SQL server 2016

Tags: r, sql-server-2016

How to install a particular R package dplyr  on SQL Server 2016. How we can install this package on SQL Server 2016.

I am trying to install dplyr on server side :

```
lib.SQL<-"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER2016\\R_SERVICES\\library"
install.packages("dplyr",lib=lib.SQL)
```

Its getting installed.
But while loading

```
library("dplyr")
```

Its throwing error , library not found

[image]

[I followed this link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/bi/using-r-package-within-sql-server-real-time-analysis-power-bi/)

after installing i was still getting error while loading dplyr package.

Comment: Images of code, and images of parts of an error aren't helpful. Both are text, so please post them as (quoted) `text`. Thank you.

Comment: please do check  now

Comment: @Shubh explain what you actually did. Screenshots don't help. It looks like you followed the [Use R package managers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/use-r-package-managers-on-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) article and tried to use `RGui` to install the package. Instead of just installing it, as the instructions show, you tried to specify another path. Why? Did you try using just the package name? Did you get an error and thought you need to add a path?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use dplyr after adding its dependencies :

- `DBI`
- `assertthat`
- `Rcpp`
- `magrittr`
- `tibble`

After that, the command :

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language =N'R', @script=N'library(dplyr)';
```

returned :

```
STDERR message(s) from external script: 

Attaching package: 'dplyr'

The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

Installing packages *into* SQL Server is a security and reliability risk which is why a package can't install its dependencies itself. After all, a package installation will affect *all* users and packages that run on that server. A single incompatibility could break everyone's scripts.

That's why the DBA has to install all required dependencies separately.

Simply installing `dplyr` and trying to use it will return errors saying that the dependencies are missing. Unfortunately, the error message only mentions the first package that failed to load.

Comment: I was able to solve this by doing : trace(utils:::unpackPkgZip, edit=TRUE)  and increasing the Sys.sleep to (2)

Comment: error which i was getting from installing dplyr in SQL server

Comment: @Shubh which you never posted. `trace` and `sleep` won't install missing packages. I tried to guess what you did, reproduce all steps that could have gotten to an error and found that dependencies aren't installed, with a multiline error that contained `library not found` *and* the name of the missing libraries. That's how I loaded all missing dependencies. If you have a different error include it in the question itself

Comment: could not find function "%>%"